# mysqldump generates 0kb sql file

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on backup and recovery of mySQL database using mysqldump. My code generates an sql file but its empty. Here's my complete code. Thanks a lot.

```
<?
   shell_exec("mysqldump -u root -p ilamdb > db/ilamdb.sql");
   echo "Back up complete.";
?>
```

Comment: There is probably an error. You've already redirected the stdout to a file; try redirecting the stderr to another file (`2>anotherfile`) so you can capture the error message and look at it afterwards.

Comment: I've tried placing the file outside the folder but it has the same result. The page will display the string, file on the folder but still empty.

Comment: OK, but that has nothing to do with what I suggested...

Comment: Can you explain much further what you've suggested?

Comment: You are already capturing the stdout of the command into a file (with `> db/ilamdb.sql`). I suggest that you *also* capture the stderr (with `2>anotherfile`) so that you will be able to see the error message that the `mysqldump` command produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the option `-p` which tells `mysqldump` to ask you for a password – which of course only works in an interactive shell. You will have to specify your password directly:

```
shell_exec("mysqldump -u root --password=yourpassword ilamdb > db/ilamdb.sql");
```

If you don't use a password, simply leave out this parameter:

```
shell_exec("mysqldump -u root ilamdb > db/ilamdb.sql");
```

Comment: syntax should be `mysqldump -uroot -pyourpassword ilamdb > db/ilamdb.sql`

Comment: what if , if my mysql doesnt have a password?

Comment: If you don't have a password, leave out the `-p` in your code.

Comment: perfect: shell_exec("mysqldump -u root ilamdb > db/ilamdb.sql"); worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL backup syntax should be as below

mysqldump -u  --password=  >File.dmp