# 0kb backup using mysqldump

Tags: python, mysql

> Same question has been asked [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/59599/58525) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15293814/2660342) but these are not helping me out.

In my `python` utility, I'm trying to take MySQL database backup using `mysqldump`. It runs successfully but I'm getting 0kb file in my backup folder.

This is my code;

```
DB_HOST = '192.168.1.1'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_USER_PASSWORD = '_root_user_password_'
DB_NAME = 'db_name'
BACKUP_PATH = '/backup/dbbackup/'

DATETIME = time.strftime('%m%d%Y-%H%M%S')
TODAYBACKUPPATH = BACKUP_PATH + DATETIME

dumpcmd = "mysqldump -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + DB_NAME + " > " + TODAYBACKUPPATH + "/" + DB_NAME + ".sql"

os.system(dumpcmd)
```

Can anyone guide me out that what I'm missing here??

Answer (score 1):

You could analyse the code in a python console (just execute `python` at the shell command line), and find some problems:

First, an import is missing at the top of the code:

```
import time, os
```

Second, the `db` variable is not set, I guess this should be `DB_NAME`. A good practice in python is to concatenate strings by using `%`-formatting:

```
dumpcmd = "mysqldump -h %s -u %s -p%s %s > %s/%s.sql" % (DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_USER_PASSWORD,DB_NAME,TODAYBACKUPPATH,DB_NAME,)
```

Finally, as a hint, add `print dumpcmd` and test the command manually.

Keep in mind that the path should be created first, or replace the `/` by `-` for the filename.

Comment: 1. All imports are already added in file.
2. db variable was a typo. Corrected.
3. Path has already been created.

Comment: issue is somewhat with mysqldump file path... Not sure how to give full path of my local C drive

Comment: If you are on Windows (local C drive) the path is different, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2953834/2025944