# Misuse of shell builtins : mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

> Starting backup...
>
> Dumping database hms...
>
> Backup failed because The dump process failed with exitcode 2 : Misuse of shell builtins : mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106 "Unknown error")" when trying to connect\r\n

I got the following error while trying to

> Artisan::call('backup:run');
>
> $output=Artisan::output();

using **php artisan backup:run** on the command line works fine.
[image]

calling it laravel's Artisan gives that error.

I correctly assign the **config/database.php** dump

```
'mysql' => [
            ...
            'dump' => [
               'dump_binary_path' => 'C:\xampp\mysql\bin',
               'use_single_transaction',
               'timeout' => 60 * 5, 
               'exclude_tables' => ['table1', 'table2'],
            ]  
        ],
```

Please, help me.

Comment: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/search?q=Misuse+of+shell+builtins&type=Issues

Comment: I try to all issues in github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/... but, anyone does not help me.

Answer (score 1):

I had invested a lot of time, particularly in this specific issue and found the solution in my case...as `php artisan backup: run` command successfully backups the database using CLI...so there is no issue with the package itself...
I'm using `"spatie/laravel-backup": "^6.16"`

**route/web.php** create a route to test the artisan command

```
Route::get('/backup', function() {
  Artisan::call('backup:run'); 
});
```

As I can see when we try to launch the laravel application we use CLI for example:

`php artisan serve`
then your project will host on
`127.0.0.1:8080/project/` or any given port.

Instead, try to access the project directly from your localhost without artisan  and then navigate to your project directory from the address bar
`localhost/project/backup` now, it will generate a backup in `storage/app/public/` directory.

Must try this if you tried everything...

Answer (score 0):

**Just put your project `C:\xampp\htdocsfolder` in and open it in a browser:

`yourdomain/PROJECT-NAME/public`

it works fine for me**

Answer (score 0):

Try this way, I had the same issue, the `artisan backup:run` successfully generating the backup but when I try to call it using `Artisan` from route or controller, I got the same error, but I found another solution for it, which I'm using here `Shell_exec` make sure its enabled in your `xampp/wamp`

**Note:** I'm using `PHP 7.4.29`

**Check if `shell_exec` is Enabled**

```
if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
    echo "shell_exec is enabled";
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/export',function(){
    shell_exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root test > C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/main.sql");
  });
```

**Also check this reference for help:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294585/13804634

I also, open a dispute on `spatie/laravel-backup` but, I guess there is a problem in my environment.
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/1578

**Make sure your `mysqldump` set in your environment variables**
['mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354510/mysqldump-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

for me, in this case php artisan serve is not working.

and i try virtualhost for run aplication in locale.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName apps.web
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\public"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\public>"
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all granted
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling,
This is my work around, and works quite well if everything is set correctly.

**1. If you are using Filament-Spatie-Laravel-Backup by shuvroroy**

- Create Filament Page and Extend class **ShuvroRoy\FilamentSpatieLaravelBackup\Pages\Backups**

Like:

```php
<?php

use ShuvroRoy\FilamentSpatieLaravelBackup\Pages\Backups as UIBackup;

class Backups extends UIBackup 
{


}
```

**2. Now, override method **create()** from this class.**

```php
public function create(string $option = ''): void
{
   
}
```

**3. Inside this function, Make a variable to contain your command, which first goes to laravel's home directory where *artisan* is located and then execute the artisan command, use php's *shell_exec()* function to execute your command as:**

```php
public function create(string $option = ''): void
{
   $command = "cd " . base_path() . " && php artisan backup:run";

   $output = shell_exec( $command );
}
```

**4. If you want to include flags, like *--only-db*, then add them to your command as**

```php
$command = "cd " . base_path() . " && php artisan backup:run";
$command .= !empty($option)? " --{$option}" : "";
```

**5. Finally, inside *AdminPanelProvider.php*, within Filament Provider, inside *plugins([])*, include the following line inside the array, Backups being subclass class above.**

```php
FilamentSpatieLaravelBackupPlugin::make()
      ->usingPage(Backups::class)
```

**N.B:** If you are using your own custom page for backups, then just use content inside the overridden method, and it should all be fine.

Answer (score -2):

Just put your project folder to `C:\xampp\htdocs` then open it at the browser:

`yourdomain/PROJECT-NAME/public`

and it just works fine for me