# Database Backup From Laravel Application

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to backup my whole Laravel application mysql database from my application by clicking a button, anyone to help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

([Laravel Backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup)) by Spatie.

this package provides you with a command (`php artisan backup:run`
). which is not exactly what you need.

But you can create a button in your admin section with a link to a route. and from there (either from the route or controller) you can call this command by

```
Artisan::call('backup:run');
```

which will trigger a backup.

Comment: It gave me an error saying "The command "backup:run" does not exist."

Comment: The dump process failed with exitcode 2 : Misuse of shell builtins : mysqldump: Got error: 2004: "Can't create TCP/IP socket (10106)" when trying to connect

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-backup/v5/introduction) is a good package for that. You can than issue the artisan command on a click of a button, or automate the way which is much better.

Answer (score 0):

read this artical https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890498/14913109

```
return response()->download($latest_filename);// read above artical
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create command 

app/Console/Commands/DatabaseBackUp.php

<?php
  
namespace App\Console\Commands;
  
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;
   
class DatabaseBackUp extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'database:backup';
  
    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';
  
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
  
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $filename = "backup-" . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".gz";
  
        $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . "  | gzip > " . storage_path() . "/app/backup/" . $filename;
  
        $returnVar = NULL;
        $output  = NULL;
  
        exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
    }
}



and in app/Console/Kernel.php

update 

  protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\DatabaseBackUp'
    ];


and run php artisan database:backup command
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
//make this code in custom command

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class DatabaseBackUp extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'database:backup';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';
    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $filename = "backup-" . Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') . ".sql";
  
        $command = "mysqldump --user=" . env('DB_USERNAME') ." --password=" . env('DB_PASSWORD') . " --host=" . env('DB_HOST') . " " . env('DB_DATABASE') . "  | gzip > " . storage_path() . "/app/backup/" . $filename;
  
        $returnVar = NULL;
        $output  = NULL;
  
        exec($command, $output, $returnVar);
    }
}
```

```html
//aadd thi in app/kernal.php 
'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
        'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
        'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
        'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
        'App\Http\Middleware\SessionExpired'
        
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\SessionExpired::class,
        ],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for it, which I'm using here `Shell_exec` make sure it's enabled in your `xampp/wamp`

**Note:** I'm using `PHP 7.4.29` on `localhost`

**Check if `shell_exec` is Enabled**

```
if(function_exists('shell_exec')) {
    echo "shell_exec is enabled";
}

shell_exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -h localhost -u root test > C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/main.sql");
```

**syntax**

```
Path to mysqldump -h [host] -u [username] -p[passowrd] [database-name] > [path/dump-name].sql
```

Note: remove -p if empty (no white space)

`C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump`
[image: mysqldump path]

`C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/main.sql` Where you want to save sql file

**Also check this reference for help:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15294585/13804634

**Make sure your `mysqldump` set in your environment variables if**
['mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31354510/mysqldump-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Answer (score 0):

### Export Only Table Data Backup without structure with row limit

---

#### Keynote:

- API
- Zip Download
- Only data backup not structure

  - Order by 1 column
  - No need mysql dump permission
  - DB Data Export with row limit
  - Exclude specific tables data to export

#### - In Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/db-migration', 'middleware'=>'auth:api'], function (){

    Route::post('server-db-structure-backup', [DBController::class, 'serverDBStructureBackup']);
    Route::post('server-db-data-backup', [DBController::class, 'serverDBDataBackup']);
    Route::post('server-db-status', [DBController::class, 'serverDBStatus']);

});
```

#### - In Controller

```
public function serverDBDataBackup(Request $request)  // db data backup only
    {
        $dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/db/backups/';
        File::ensureDirectoryExists($dir);
        $file_name = 'db_backup_'.Str::slug(getNow(), '_').'.sql';
        $file_full_url = $dir.$file_name;
        $file = fopen($file_full_url, 'w');

        $databaseName = DB::getDatabaseName();
        $table_names = DB::table('information_schema.tables')
                        ->where('table_schema', $databaseName)
                        ->where('TABLE_TYPE', 'BASE TABLE')
                        // ->where('table_name', 'users')  // later remove
                        ->when($request->filled('except_tables') && count($request->except_tables), function ($q){
                            $q->whereNotIn('table_name', request('except_tables'));
                        })
                        ->pluck('table_name')
                        ->toArray();



        // Loop through the tables and export data into files
        foreach ($table_names as $table_name)
        {
            $data = DB::table($table_name) // getting a table dataset using select
                    ->when($request->filled('table_rules') && count($request->table_rules), function ($q) use($request, $table_name)  // executing all rules
                    {
                        foreach ($request->table_rules as $key => $rule)
                        {
                            if (isset($rule['table_name']) && $rule['table_name']==$table_name && isset($rule['row_limit']))   // for table row limit
                            {
                                $q->limit($rule['row_limit']);
                            }

                            if (isset($rule['table_name']) && $rule['table_name']==$table_name && isset($rule['order_by']) && isset($rule['order_type']))   // for table order by
                            {
                                $q->orderBy($rule['order_by'], $rule['order_type']);
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    ->get();

            if ($data->count() > 0)
            {
                fwrite($file, PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.'-- ==================Table: '.$table_name.'================== '.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL);

                foreach ($data as $row)
                {
                    $insert = "INSERT INTO `$table_name` (";
                    $values = "VALUES (";

                    foreach ($row as $column => $value)
                    {
                        $insert .= "`$column`, ";
                        $values .= "'" . addslashes($value) . "', ";
                    }

                    $insert = rtrim($insert, ', ') . ")";
                    $values = rtrim($values, ', ') . ");\n";

                    fwrite($file, $insert . " " . $values);
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($file); // close the file

        $zip_file_full_url = substr($file_full_url, 0, -3).'zip'; // zip full url
        $zip_file_name = substr($file_name, 0, -3).'zip'; // zip file name
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $zip->open($zip_file_full_url, ZipArchive::CREATE); // open the zip archive
        $zip->addFile($file_full_url, $file_name); // add file to zip archive
        $zip->close(); // close the file

        File::delete($file_full_url);  // after zip delete the sql file

        return Response::download($zip_file_full_url, $zip_file_name, [ // download the zip file
            'Content-Type' => 'application/zip',
        ]);
    }
```

#### - In Postman request

```
//except_tables[0]:activity_log
except_tables[1]:audit_trail
table_rules[0][table_name]:users
table_rules[0][row_limit]:10
table_rules[1][table_name]:activity_log
table_rules[1][row_limit]:10
table_rules[1][order_by]:id
table_rules[1][order_type]:DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you database is large then mysql dump process consume large amount of
memory when you database backup start from mysql dump then it may case to
your site is slow and site is not working this issue i have facing in my site.

I have create db:backup command and use I/O input and tee it will help
manage server memory now i have dump approx 40 gb and it will take 4 mintues but still my site in not slow.
Please check below example

1. Use the make:command command to create a new command. Simply pass in the command name, like so:

   php artisan make:command DBBackup

2)To do this, update the $signature property of the command, like this:

```
protected $signature = 'db:backup';
```

3)To do this, update the $description property to match this:

```
protected $description = 'Backup the database';
```

4)protected $process;

5)add below namespace if not exit

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

    use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
```

6)app/Console/Commands/DBBackup.php

DB command full example

```
<?php



namespace App\Console\Commands;



use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;



class DBBackup extends Command

{

    /**

     * The name and signature of the console command.

     *

     * @var string

     */

    protected $signature = 'db:backup';

    /**

     * The console command description.

     *

     * @var string

     */

    protected $description = 'Backup the database';

    protected $process;

    /**

     * Create a new command instance.

     *

     * @return void

     */

    public function __construct()

    {

        parent::__construct();

        $fileName='sample_'.date("Y-m-d").'.sql';

        

        

         $this->process = new Process(sprintf(

            'mysqldump -u%s -p%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s  > %s',

            config('database.connections.mysql.username'),

            config('database.connections.mysql.password'),

            config('database.connections.mysql.database'),

            '--single-transaction',

            '--quick',

            '|',

            'ionice',

            '-c2',

            '-n',

            '7',

            'tee',

            storage_path('backups/'.$fileName)

        ));

        

     

    }



    /**

     * Execute the console command.

     *

     * @return mixed

     */

    public function handle()

    {

         try {

            $this->process->setTimeout(null);

            $this->process->setIdleTimeout(null);

            $this->process->mustRun();

            $this->info('The backup has been proceed successfully.');

        } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {

            $this->error('The backup process has been failed.');

        }

    }

}
```

and you can set cron as per below

```
 Command : 17   20  *   *   *   php /var/www/html/sample/artisan db:backup >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

For more information Please chek this [link](https://myphpinformation.blogspot.com/2024/01/laravel-database-backup-using-laravel-command-without-minimum-mysql-dump-load.html)