# Laravel 5.7 : Export the database using button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

We have 3 users. 1) Superadmin; 2) Super Users; 3) Users. In our application, we want to have export the database to .sql file so that we will have backup.

We added the button "Export Database" but this button is for superadmin only.

**school database**

```
// Tables
users

roles
```

When I clicked the "Export Database", my "school" database will be export to .sql

Question: Is it possible to export the database without any tools?

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up on roles and permissions.

Comment: Roles and permissions of what?

Comment: Implementing user roles and permissions in Laravel.

Comment: Wups, i think my question is not clear. What I mean is export the entire database.

Comment: I think you need to add more context to your question. Are you trying to export the database on the command line or using a tool? What is the RDMS? What does Laravel have to do with the question, if you're not trying to implement the functionality within the app?

Comment: I updated my post, may I know what is RDMS? can you give me a brief explanation about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222294/database-backup-from-laravel-application

Comment: This is what Im looking for! Thanks!